# Entropy and Dissipation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

I've grown accustomed to thinking of entropy as something that reduces the amount of mechanical work a system can produce. However, this does not seem to be reflected in the mathematics.

For example, consider a system consisting of an ideal gas that may exchange work and heat with its surroundings. The Helmholtz free energy of the gas is then

$$ F = U - TS. $$

Now, suppose the system undergoes an arbitrary transformation in $(V,p)$ space. Then, we have

\begin{align} dF & = q - w - TdS - SdT \\\\ & \le-w - SdT. \end{align}

What I find striking is that the change in entropy does not affect the ability of the system to do mechanical work. Or, at the very least, we cannot determine by how much the change in entropy degrades the energy of the system.

Comment: See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al, Chapter 11, Homework Problem 11.D.1 for a derivation of an expression for the local rate of entropy generation in a system as a result of viscous dissipation and finite rate of heat conduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've grown accustomed to thinking of entropy as something that reduces
> the amount of mechanical work a system can produce

You are referring to entropy that is *generated* as a result of irreversible work or irreversible heat transfer. That results in less mechanical work being produced than the case where entropy is strictly transferred as a result of a reversible transfer of heat.

Consider the example of a reversible isothermal expansion of an ideal gas versus an irreversible expansion between the same two equilibrium states, both involving a constant temperature surroundings. See the figure below. (Note, for the irreversible path the term "isothermal" refers to only to the  temperature of the system at the boundary with the surroundings. The temperature within the system varies spatially).

For the reversible path the external pressure is slowly (quasi-statically) reduced so that the temperature of the gas remains constant (i.e. $PV=$constant) with the gas in thermal and mechanical equilibrium with the surroundings at all times. The reversible work, $w_{rev}$, is the area under the reversible path.

For the irreversible path in the constant temperature surroundings, the external pressure is suddenly reduced to the final pressure and the gas allowed to expand rapidly (and irreversibly) at constant external pressure until thermal and mechanical  equilibrium is reached at the final state. The irreversible work, $w_{irr}$, is the area under the irreversible path.

Note that the area under the irreversible path is less than under the reversible path. Thus

$$w_{irr}\lt w_{rev}$$

In contrast to the reversible path, for the irreversible path heat is added only during the constant external pressure rapid expansion whereas in the reversible path heat is added throughout the expansion. The less heat added over the irreversible path results in less energy available for performing mechanical work.

Note that the change in entropy *of the system*  between the initial and final equilibrium states is the same for both the reversible and irreversible path, as it must be since entropy is a state function independent of the path. However, for the irreversible path, the change in entropy of the system consists of two components, entropy transferred from the surroundings plus entropy generated within the system due to the rapid irreversible expansion. (see @Chet Miller comment for a reference). For the reversible path the entropy change of the system consists only of the reversible transfer of entropy.

For the irreversible path there is less heat transferrer to the system from the surroundings for doing work. This means, for the irreversible path, the decrease in entropy of the surroundings will be less than the increase in entropy of the system. Thus

$$\Delta s_{tot}=\Delta s_{sys}+\Delta s_{surr}\gt 0$$

For the reversible path the increase in entropy of the system equals the decrease in entropy of the surroundings. Thus

$$\Delta s_{tot}=\Delta s_{sys}+\Delta s_{surr}= 0$$

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This was great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"*I've grown accustomed to thinking of entropy as something that reduces the amount of mechanical work a system can produce.*"

This a wrong way of thinking of entropy. In fact, entropy transported from a higher to a lower temperature is what makes a heat engine produce mechanical work. In a reversible process the total entropy including the engine and its surroundings is conserved.

The conceptual and fundamental difference between the conservation of entropy and the conservation of, say, electric charge or gravitational mass, etc., is that the latter extensive quantities are unconditionally conserved in *all* processes while entropy is conserved only in a reversible process but increases in an irreversible one. The actual increase of entropy at some temperature at a a given locality is how dissipation manifests itself numerically in an irreversible process at that spatial point.

Note that the conservation of these extensive quantities including mass, charge, etc., *and* entropy is not to be understood just globally in a sense that between, say, two equilibrium states bracketing a process, but during the process itself at any instant or any stage and at any locality in *detail*.